# Dynamic created variables inside for loop, Javascript

Tags: javascript

Creating static variables is not an option in this case becouse it would take to long time and ineffective to what im trying to accomplish. I have an `Array` with images and I'm trying to create a way to make divs according to the length of the array. 1,2,3,4 etc.

```
var images = ['image1.JPG', 'image2.JPG', 'image3.JPG'];
var totalimages = images.length;
```

Which will result in an `array` length of 3. I would like to create 3 variables for this.

```
for (var i = 0; i > totalimages; i++){
  var div[i] = document.createElement('div');

}
```

This seems not to be working for some reason. I tried to create a div array/list outside the for loop aswell.

```
var div = [];

for (var i = 0; i > totalimages; i++){
  var div[i] = document.createElement('div');

}
```

Still not working. I dunno why this is not working. Javascript only

EDIT: (not working) i mean it gives me syntax error.

Comment: define 'not working'.

Comment: Remove the `var` inside the loop.

Comment: Have you actually created an object called `div`?

Comment: var inside the loop was the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined `div` already. In loop you shouldn't be saying like `var div` again.

BTW `var div[` will cause a syntax error.

Use this

```
div[i] = document.createElement('div');
```

instead of

```
var div[i] = document.createElement('div');
```

Any way I'll prefer saying this at that place

```
div.push(document.createElement('div'));
```

And this will cause `i > totalimages` an infinitive loop, say `i < totalimages` instead.

Comment: To clarify, the problem is not that he variable is already declared, `var div[` is simply invalid syntax.

Answer (score 1):

```
i < totalimages
```

**not**

```
i > totalimages
```

Make sure you don't use `var` inside the array if you're assigning new values:

```
var div = [];
for (var i = 0; i < totalimages; i++){
  div[i] = document.createElement('div');
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sk0zLrsr/1/)

Comment: Yeah, but it still dosent slove my problem with dynamic variables.

Answer (score 0):

In short:

```
var images = ['image1.JPG', 'image2.JPG', 'image3.JPG'];
var totalimages = images.length;
var div = [];

for (var i = 0; i < totalimages; i++){
  div.push(document.createElement('div'));
}
```